# How can I use case information in a new column in SQL?

Tags: sql, case-statement

I am learning SQL from an online tutorial series and in this video we learned how to use case statements.

I understand how to use it, but then I thought about "well can I use the new data from the column I made?" I tried playing around and added in another CASE statement to try and use the `UpdatedSalary` column, but it wouldn't work. I tried googling a bunch, but I really don't know how to word the question.

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, Salary,
    CASE 
        WHEN JobTitle = 'Salesman' THEN Salary + (Salary * .10)
        WHEN JobTitle = 'Accountant' THEN Salary + (Salary * .05)
        WHEN Jobtitle = 'HR' THEN Salary + (Salary * .00001)
        ELSE Salary + (Salary * .03)
    END AS UpdatedSalary
    CASE 
        WHEN UpdatedSalary > 0 THEN UpdatedSalary - Salary 
        ELSE 
    END AS NetIncrease
FROM 
    SQLTutorial.dbo.EmployeeDemographics
JOIN 
    SQLTutorial.dbo.EmployeeSalary ON EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID = EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID
```

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: The `dbo` part as the table name suggests SQL Server, but let's the OP confirm.

Comment: You are right @Alejandro. I should have noticed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use column alias like this if you want to use this you need to put same condition in both the columns or need to use outer query.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, Salary,
CASE 
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Salesman'
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .10)
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Accountant'
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .05)
    WHEN Jobtitle = 'HR' 
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .00001)
    ELSE Salary + (Salary * .03)
END
AS UpdatedSalary,

CASE 
    WHEN (CASE 
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Salesman'
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .10)
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Accountant'
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .05)
    WHEN Jobtitle = 'HR' 
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .00001)
    ELSE Salary + (Salary * .03)
END)> 0
    THEN (CASE 
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Salesman'
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .10)
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Accountant'
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .05)
    WHEN Jobtitle = 'HR' 
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .00001)
    ELSE Salary + (Salary * .03)
END)- Salary 
    ELSE
END
AS NetIncrease

FROM SQLTutorial.dbo.EmployeeDemographics
JOIN SQLTutorial.dbo.EmployeeSalary
    ON EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID = EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID
```

Or

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, Salary,UpdatedSalary,
CASE 
    WHEN UpdatedSalary > 0
    THEN UpdatedSalary - Salary 
    ELSE
END
AS NetIncrease

from (
SELECT FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, Salary,
CASE 
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Salesman'
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .10)
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Accountant'
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .05)
    WHEN Jobtitle = 'HR' 
    THEN Salary + (Salary * .00001)
    ELSE Salary + (Salary * .03)
END
AS UpdatedSalary


FROM SQLTutorial.dbo.EmployeeDemographics
JOIN SQLTutorial.dbo.EmployeeSalary
    ON EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID = EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID)t
```

Comment: Thank you all very much. I am indeed using MSSql.

Comment: you can not use Alias UpdatedSalary in another column or where clause but you can use it in order by clause.